# how to use touchesBegan and touchesEnded?

Tags: swift, touchesbegan, touchesended

I added below codes on ViewController

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("started")
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("ended")
}
```

but it doesn't print any messages at all.

Comment: Try putting these on a view instead of a view controller. (I was surprised to see these can be overridden on a UIViewController.)

Comment: @dfd I am a beginner of Swift. could you let me know how to put these codes on View, not ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UIResponder class is an abstract interface for responding to and
>   handling events
>   [Apple API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder)

UIWindow, UIViewController, UIView are subclass of UIResponder

if you want to use `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`, override it

touch event follow responder chain refer [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html)

[image]

some touch event occur and your ViewController's view become next responder and hittest successfully `touchesBegan` called when touch began and `touchesEnded` called touch ended

Comment: I did override on the above code on UIViewController. Is it wrong?